# How can I reference images in my HTML document when the page is being accessed on disk?

Tags: html, css

I created and deployed a webpage locally on my hard disk and found that nothing is working as I expected. All code for my website is structured in the following format:

default.html
images/tpc/....  [all images here]
js/              [all js file is here]

And my HTML looks something like this:

```
 <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img alt="" height="16" src="/images/tpc/slide-butn.png" width="15">
    </a>
 </li>
```

This is creating a problem, when another person open the default.html page from their own disk, I suppose the image links are getting referred to as:

```
file:///C:/images/tpc/slide-butn.png
```

Is there something I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a relative URL?

```
<img alt="" height="16" src="images/tpc/slide-butn.png" width="15">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relative path:

```
src="images/tpc/slide-butn.png"
```

(first slash omitted)

Answer (score 0):

Most websites need to be tested using a webserver, not just opening random files. There may not necessarily be a way to "fix" it so that you can directly open the files. If a URL starts with "/", then it is relative to the domain on which the file is served, which may have a different effect than a relative URL, depending on what file the domain-relative URL appears on. My suggestion would be to develop  a standard mechanism for testing your website, such as a command that can start up a demo webserver in a similar configuration to that of the real website, or some shared testing server.

Note that even if you change everything to relative URLs, you will run into similar trouble when it comes to headers set by the webserver, cookies, any sort of dynamic or interpreted pages, mime types, etc.  at some point if you just open files rather than use a test web server, so might as well bite the bullet now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the leading slash and make the urls relative to the file save location.

For example, if your images are in a directory named images in the directory where your html file is, the correct url would be

```
<img alt="" height="16" src="images/tpc/slide-butn.png" width="15">
```

This says you look in the images directory in the same directory as the file. With the leading slash, the browser will look in the root. Great great for a website, not so much for a local directory.

This post on [relative and absolute urls](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3) should give you a better explanation.